# prestashop blank index (problems in javascript?)

Tags: prestashop

i do not know why but my prestashop just stopped working.
i do have access to most of the admin site... but not the frontend.

http://www.peruzza.eu/

javamachine is giving an error on 
https://static.dreamsadnetwork.com/chromeapp/det/det.js on line

```
var title = "title=" + document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText;
```

saying that it cannot read property innerText

i do not know... i havent change anytings... in firefox doesent work as well

Comment: That means JS parser can not find <title> tag in HTML document

Answer (score 0):

The page is returning 500 error, which means there is something wrong with the script. It can't be the JavaScript file, because JS is executed on client side, which meean that there must be something wrong with PHP.

A lot of the times it is just a missing semicolon or incorrectly copied override; To see the error there are two ways:

```
config/defines.inc.php
Line 29: define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

Change it to true and you will the error  displayed on your page. However, this is not recommended if your shop is live because customers will be seeing this too (but it is down anyway, so...).

```
phpinfo.php
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Make a file `phpinfo.php` in the root directory and paste this code. Find the line `error log` and see if a file path is set. If not, go back tot top and see which `php.ini` is loaded. If you can set the error log file in this `.ini` file. Then you should locate the error log file as see the error of your website.

Comment: Then close this question, and post a new one with the error